# Тире здесь или запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно? Это песня «Последний раз» М. Боярского.

> Прежде чем пуститься **в путь — / Прошлое** перечеркнуть; / Прежде чем мосты спалить, двери затворить, / — оглянись назад, постой. / Вспомни, сколько нам с тобой / Выпало счастливых дней, ветреных путей и дождей.

> Прежде чем пуститься **в путь, / Прошлое** перечеркнуть; / Прежде чем мосты спалить, двери затворить, / — оглянись назад, постой. / Вспомни, сколько нам с тобой / Выпало счастливых дней, ветреных путей и дождей.